# How to combine queries for empty values in Solr?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to query solr docs with empty field values and am not able to get it going:

Let's say the docs have two potentially empty fields `name_de` and `name_en`.

Querying for *one of those* as described [in the solr docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/the-standard-query-parser.html#differences-between-lucenes-classic-query-parser-and-solrs-standard-query-parser) works fine:

`-name_de:[* TO *]`

But as soon as I start to combine more than one query of that kind, the answer is not what I would expect:

`-name_de:[* TO *] OR -name_en:[* TO *]`

should deliver something like the union of both queries I would think. Yet it doesn't. I simply did not understand the answer: in my case I have 1310 docs delivered by querying for `name_de`, 1319 by querying for `name_en` - and get 950 when combining both as shown above.

As I understand the Solr docs:

> Pure negative queries (all clauses prohibited) are allowed (only as a top-level clause)

these "pure negative queries" cannot be combined and the whole functionality is not supported by Lucene out of the box but an "extension" by Solr's Standard Query Parser.

But I have not been able to find relevant resources stating that more cleary and indicating the correct handling of empty values and I wonder if my approach is wholly wrong.

Does anyone have a hint for me how to handle / query these empty values in Solr correctly?

PS:
Trying to incorporate [the exists function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/function-queries.html#exists-function) didn't work out as well: calling these always delivered all the documents, regardless of their content in `name_de` or `name_en`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you have to be more specific when you're "subtracting" something from a result:

```
(*:* -name_d:[* TO *]) OR (*:* -name_en:[* TO *])
```

In your first case `*:*` is added implicitly at the front, and since that's the only term in the query, you get the result you expect. However, in your second case, the `*:*` would only prefix the first set if present, and not the second set of documents after `OR`.

Explicitly adding the complete set of documents (represented by `*:*`) so that we have something to subtract from before finding the set of documents matching that term should do what you want.